# No guarda el registro y me sale error "This field is required" en Django

Tags: html, python, django

Al tratar de insertar un registro, me sale el error "This Field is Required" lo cual al presionar mi botón "Registrar" recarga la página y no guarda el registro. Sin embargo, en la consola si aparece que se está tomando los datos.

> Views.py

```html
class CrearIng(CreateView):
    model = Personal
    form_class = PersonalForm
    template_name = 'personal/crear.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('personal') 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) 
        form = PersonalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        self.object = None
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = "Agregar prospecto PDM"
        return context
```

> Crear.html

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Datos del empleado</h3>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.errors }}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <button type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="bi bi-cloud-arrow-up"></i> Registrar</button>           
            <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'personal' %}" role="button">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

> form.py

```html
class PersonalForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.visible_fields():
            form.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            form.field.widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        self.fields['nombre'].widget.attrs['autofocus'] = True
    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        fields = '__all__'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí está la consola donde se registra que sí está tomando los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el campo CV es un request.files, dberias hacer un presave

Comment: Como iría el código?

Comment: algo asi :p `PersonalForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Comment: Pero que tonto soy jajaja, muchas gracias master